# how to add staticfiles processing to css pages in django

Tags: html, css, django

In my CSS, I have examples like this:

```
#defaultCountdown span.countdown_section {
    color:#fff;
    padding:7px 15px!important;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    font-weight:300;
    background:url(../img/bg-white.png);
    text-align:center
}
```

If you see the background tag, there's a url.
How do I serve this via staticfiles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comment about using `static` in css or js files.... It could be done. Basically you would define a route and view just like for html pages.

**But**, this is strongly discouraged for a production level site. You will have a significant increase in page response time if you do this rather than serving these as static files.

To accomplish this, you simply pass `content_type` into your `HttpResponse` for your related view:

```
return HttpReaponse(my_dynamic_css, content_type="text/css")
```

Comment: ok, I guess the issue here is CSS3 and static files.  what you are suggesting is that we do NOT use the url() function in a css3 class if you want to keep static going.

Comment: Yeah. I would suggest either on page using <style> or an in line style.

Answer (score 0):

css is a static file, as is your images and .js. So you use relative paths to reference them, unless you've got a specific need to use static tags for backgrounds, then you can move the style tag for background outside your css and into into your html:

```
<div class="generic" id="#defaultCountdown span.countdown_section" style="background: url('{% static 'img/bg-white.png' %}');></div>
```

Comment: ok sorry.  rephrase.  How do I set static on the CSS file? and for that matter the JS file?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `{% static 'url' %}` in your CSS or JS, the easiest would be to define the CSS in a `<style>` block in your HTML template's `<head>` and the JS in a `<script>` block at the bottom of your template. Any CSS or JS that doesn't require the use of `{% static 'url' %}` can still go in separate .css and .js files.